# iphone/ipad: create a remote control freature

Tags: iphone, controller, robotics

I am quite new to iOS development and just thought to take guidance from experts

Actually I have to do a project  in which I can use iPAd/iPhone to control some external device like camera movement or anything similar like that, some PIC programming or anything related to robotics, mechanics which can be controlled from iOS based device.

I am kind of lost goggling please guide me on this.

If you can help me  with these I can get some concrete redirections

1) Links to whitepapers / articles / blogs having relevant material

2) Links of third party libraries which can help me in this

3) Links of demo application which are already there

4) What stream should I focus on to get material regarding the same.

eg: something like survilance system

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm sorry to say that, but it's going to be a challenge. We just had to go through the apple's MFI program to interface our hardware device with iOS via bluetooth. If you insist on iOS, WiFi has a better chance than Bluetooth, IMHO.

Comment: can you provide me some links to some tutorials, docs and whitepapers

Comment: sure:http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XQeZE4nh6M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the practical ways to interface an iOS device to a robot are over WiFi, establishing either a UDP or TCP socket. Here are a few links:

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/2023-tcp-ip-udp-networking.html
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XQeZE4nh6M
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0ipAKzCwn4Y

I would not recommend the Bluetooth path, as Apple considers bluetooth as an "External Accessory" and requires MFi certification (Made for iPhone)